# How to declare multiple variables in ionic 2/Angular2/typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am completely new to ionic2/Angular2/Typescript. I am creating a wheel having eight slices. I have difficulty in declaration of variables. How do I declare multiple variables?

In javascript I have declared like below:

```
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

    var color = ['#fbc','#f88','#fbc','#f88','#fbc','#f88', "#fbc", "#f67"];
    var label = ['10', '200', '50', '100', '5', '500', '0', "jPOT"];
    var slices = color.length;
    var sliceDeg = 360/slices;
    var deg = rand(0, 360);
    var speed = 0;
    var slowDownRand = 0;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var width = canvas.width; // size
    var center = width/2;      // center
    var isStopped = false;
    var lock = false;

    function deg2rad(deg) {
      return deg * Math.PI/180;
    }
```

How do I declare in ionic2 ?

Comment: dont know about ionic but in typescript use can use `var` too but there is type `let` that you can use for local scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 2 is running on top of Typescript.So you can do it as shown below.

Always try to use [**let.You can read why here**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html).

```
rand(min, max): your-return-type {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

    let color = ['#fbc','#f88','#fbc','#f88','#fbc','#f88', "#fbc", "#f67"],
       label = ['10', '200', '50', '100', '5', '500', '0', "jPOT"],
       slices = color.length,
       sliceDeg = 360/slices,
       deg = rand(0, 360),
       speed = 0,
       slowDownRand = 0,
       ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
       width = canvas.width,
       center = width/2,
       isStopped = false,
       lock = false;

    deg2rad(deg): your-return-type2 {
      return deg * Math.PI/180;
    }
```

Comment: you can also use the same `let` keyword to declare all of them like `let color = ..., label = ..., slides = ..., ....`

Comment: Thanks for the nice tip @sebaferreras

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to declare so many variables? If there are so many variables, better make a class in TypeScript and then create an object in your class and then finally assign the values to the class properties.

```
    class Wheel{
    public slices: string;
    public speed: number;
....
    }
```

This way you can define all the properties and use them wherever you want to use.